# Remove embedded font from PDF

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, itext

I switched from Delphi with a old Crystal to C# with a current crystal reports. Exporting reports to pdf within the old crystal+delphi produces pdfs without embedded fonts. With c# and the CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports it produce me reports with embedded fonts from the same report. This results in bigger filesizes (25kb -> 70kb sounds less but multiply this with some hundred exports).

Is there a way to tell crystal it should not embedded the fonts? Or if not is there a way to change the embedded fonts to non embedded ones?

**Add:** I asked at the SAP forum too: http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1916257
The only possibility is to remove the fonts from the pdf after the export. So how can I do this? Can itextsharp do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to the server, you can install Ghostscript and run the following command line:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pswrite -sOutputFile=- -q -dNOPAUSE With-Fonts.pdf -c quit | ps2pdf - > No-Fonts.pdf
```

I comes from somewhere on the web, untested - maybe this approach is helpful.

Comment: It comes from [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1666/remove-embedded-fonts-from-a-pdf.), I believe. I just tried it. First of all, as the comments say in that page, it's just a side-effect. Secondly it converts letters to vector graphics, meaning that you will NOT be able to select text in the target file; the target file will be larger; and strange anti-aliasing effects will start kicking in and blurring text at smaller zooms.